# How to find X elements from a list in a string and both elements are same

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I want to find if a string has two elements from a list which are the same, (one element appeared two times).

Here is my code:

```
List = ['XZ', 'AB', 'CD', ]

string1 = 'helloXZ worldXZ'
string2 = 'hello world'
string3 = 'hello wordCD'
string4 = 'helloXZ worldCD'

if any(s in string for s in List) and any(s == s in string for s in List):
 print ('true')
else:
 print('false')`
```

I am getting all strings true except string2, and I want all false except first one!
I tried `s==s` , `s==s*2`, `s==s+s`, and `s>=2` with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
 if string1.count(str) > 1:
      ...

 if string2.count(str) > 1:
      ...
```

instead of any()

Comment: I couldnt do it that way,
    if (s in string1 for s in List):
        for s in List:
            if string1.count(s) >1:
                print ('true')
     else:
      print('false')

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
            if any(s in string and string.count(run) > 1 for s in list) :
                    print('true')
            else:
                print('false')
```

That works!